# Adding exogenous input to data (to expand ARMAX)

Tags: matlab, dataset, arma

I am facing the following problems:

1) I am trying to add an exogenous input to an existing ARMAX model.
I already identified a good fitting model with small MSE for my system. 
`N_E = 100` experiments for the SISO stochastic system were used.

The data is in the time domain, with `361` data points for each experiment.

**Extended ARMAX:**
$$
\ A(q)y(k) = B(q)u(k) + C(q)e(t)+D(q)w(t)
$$

$w(t)$ is not an input, in the sense that I don't have control over it. But I can meassure the value, and I want to refine the model with it, since I'm certain that it has a linear influence on the output $y(t)$.

**Question**: is the reasoning correct? Is this procedure standard? Did I oversee literature where this is treated?

---

2) With the knowledge of 1), how can I expand the data-set to a MISO system with the additional ex. input. $w(t)$ in MATLAB?

So far I have done the following (of course, it is oversimplified here)

```
y = cell(1,N_E);
u = cell(1,N_E);
period = cell(1,N_E);
for i = 1:N_E
    [y{i},u{i},period{i}] = simulate_system();
end
data = iddata(y,u,period);
orders = get_orders(data);
arx_sys = arx(data,orders);
```

where `get_orders` is a function that guesses the orders with `selstruc` and other MATLAB functions designed for this.

**Question**: adding the exogenous input would only be calling `arx` with `u` being a `2`x`N_E` cell array?

I have tried that, and reading as much as possible from the [mathworks documentation](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/iddata.html) (and many other sites from the *System Identification toolbox*) without success.

---

P.S. if the problem is not clear enough please let me know.
Also, if other stackexchange site is more appropiate (stackoverflow? dsp?) please let me know, so that I post the question there.

Comment: Wait, the fact that w(t) is observable but not controllable makes it an input under the ARMAX framework. Thus it is numerically desirable the inputs of an identifiable model to be as stochastic as practically possible. Treat w(t) as an input. Under that reasoning, B and D are a single matrix, and the C matrix will contain only non observable (non measurable) input noises.

Comment: IF you are not clear with the code, just write me up...

Comment: This site is appropiate, as long as i am here to answer you lol.